# 初回のpushでエラーとなる

Tags: github

`git push -u origin main`
を行うと
`error: src refspec main does not match any error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/kazu1212-star/study-typescript.git'`
と表示されます。

色々試してみましたが解決しませんでした。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `git commit`はされていますか？cf:[git push時のerror: src refspec master does not match anyについて](https://blog.deepblue-ts.co.jp/git/git-push-error/), [Gitでerror: src refspec master does not match anyのエラー](https://qiita.com/maominionbsk54/items/de00bbba78074fdd7325)

Comment: エラーの出ている URL はブラウザで開いても 404 エラーが表示されます。プライベートリポジトリでない限り、まずはリポジトリを作成する必要がありそうです。

Comment: 解決しました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まずは、そのリポジトリをcloneして、それでできた作業フォルダにファイル追加、修正を加え、pushしてみよう